# Converting DateFormat /Date(1587513600000)/

Tags: t-sql, datetime, azure-sql-database

In my database I have a value that is stored as a nvarchar(1000):

```
/Date(1587513600000)/
```

This is apparently called the Microsoft JSON Dateformat

I know that this value represents  the date

```
2020-04-22T00:00:00Z
```

Can I translate this string into a dateformat that Azure SQL understands using only TSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the value is the number of miliseconds sinds 1970-01-01.  So you could something like this:

```
DECLARE @jsonDate varchar(1000) = '/Date(1587513600000)/'

SELECT DATEADD(s,CAST(SUBSTRING(@jsonDate,7,len(@jsonDate)-11) as INT),'1970-01-01')
```